# Proof of a Separating Hyperplane Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, constructive-mathematics

SEP: Let Y be a convex, located and inhabited set in $ \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $0 \notin Y$. Fix $y^1,\dots,y^l$ in Y. Then there exists and $ \xi \in Y$ such that
\begin{align*}
(\langle \xi, y^1 \rangle , \dots, \langle \xi , y^l \rangle ) >0,
\end{align*}
meaning all entries of the vector are nonnegative and at least one is greater $0$.

LLPO: $\forall x , y \in \mathbb{R} : x \ge 0 \vee x \le 0$.

I am trying to prove constructively that LLPO implies SEP.

I tried to do this by induction:

The case $n=1$ is trivial.

For the general case I tried to split $Y$ into two sets. $Y_1 = \{ y \in Y : y_n = 0\}$ and $Y_2 = \{ y \in Y : y_1 = \dots = y_{n-1} = 0\}$.

The problem however is now, that in order to apply the Induction Hypothesis, I need that $Y_1$ is convex and $ 0 \notin Y_1$. But this does not necessarily hold. Is there a more sophisticated way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your two sets $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ do not contain enough information to determine the set $Y$ uniquely.
If $Y$ is a ball that doesn't meet any of the coordinate axes, then $Y_1=\emptyset$ and $Y_2=\emptyset$.

Here is one way to prove what you want.
The key is the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** Suppose $Y$ is closed and convex. If $0\notin Y$, the vector $\xi$ which minimizes the distance from $0$ to $Y$ (i.e. $|\xi|=d(0,Y)$) satisfies $\langle\xi,y\rangle>0$ for all $y\in Y$.

To prove this, you only need to observe that if $\langle\xi,x\rangle\leq0$ for some $x\in Y$, then the line joining $\xi$ and $x$ is also in $Y$ by convexity and you can argue that this line has a point closer to the origin than $\xi$, contradicting the choice of $\xi$.
(You may argue that this is not constructive. For me this still counts as constructive: The vector $\xi$ is given explicitly. Then it is proven that the choice cannot fail the desired property. Perhaps there are more constructive variants of the same argument if that is an issue.)

In your original problem you can then define $Y'$ to be the convex hull of the points $y^1,\dots,y^l$.
This defines a convex and compact set contained in $Y$.
Since $0\notin Y$, we also have $0\notin Y'$.
Apply the lemma to the set $Y'$ and you are done.

Some additional remarks:

- Showing that the line has a closer point than $\xi$:
  The line is not perpendicular to $\xi$ because otherwise $\langle\xi,\cdot\rangle$ would be constant on the line.
  Therefore the line is not tangent to the sphere $S(0,|\xi|)$ but actually goes inside it.
  To see this more rigorously, you can take the direction vector $v=x-y$ of the line and see that the condition on the inner products implies $\langle\xi,v\rangle<0$.
  Thus the function $t\mapsto|\xi+tv|^2$ has a negative derivative at $t=0$, showing that it takes lower values than $|\xi|$.
  You can also use tools from linear algebra.
- The convex hull of a finite set is always compact.
  However, for this argument it is enough that it's closed.
  The proofs I have seen are somewhat involved, although the result is easy to believe.
  Perhaps you could somehow argue that the convex hull is a finite intersection of finitely many closed half spaces (from which closedness follows easily)?
  (Also, I would argue that the construction is explicit, and non-constructive arguments are only used to show that it cannot fail. I see compactness falling in this category. What constructivity means is a matter of taste.)
- The proof I presented is constructive in the following sense: It provides a method (which can be implemented numerically) to find such a vector $\xi$, given the points and the set. In my field (inverse problems) this is understood as a constructive proof. The proof that the suggested method works may use any logical tools. I know that in many other fields constructivity means other things, and in some respects this proof will almost certainly not count as constructive. This answer is from my perspective, which is all I can do, as no specific meaning for constructivity was given in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still have two questions: How do I argue that a point closer to the origin exists on this line? And second, why is the convex hull compact; or more precisely how do I show this constructively?

Comment: @Diamir I added remarks on those questions.

Comment: thanks for the additional remarks. Constructivity means in my case not using the law of excluded middle. So some of your arguments might not work in the way you proposed. However, I am thankful for the input and hopefully will manage to make the proof fully constructive.

Comment: How you intend to (mis)use a word may be a matter of taste, but there are quite objective meanings to the notion of "constructive". It is not a matter of taste whether your proof can be formalized into a system of constructive logic or whether the statement is even a theorem in those systems. Even the choice of using such systems is not merely a matter of philosophical preference. For example, a constructive proof can be translated to a statement about sheaves, while a non-constructive proof likely cannot.

Comment: @DerekElkins I know there are objective meanings, but different people and fields have quite different views, so I intentionally left it open-ended. In my field people would often call a proof constructive it is (more or less) implementable as an algorithm, but the logical tools used to prove that the algorithm will work are not limited. The OP mentioned no specific technical meaning, so I kept my discussion general (and, arguably, vague).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta If you gave a "lowest common denominator" proof that would work in any/most constructive logics, you'd have a point, but the proof you've given isn't obviously constructive in *any* sense. If there is some specific "constructive" system where your proof is vaild, you should say what it is and that you don't know if the proof works in other systems. Ideally, you would point out where the potentially problematic parts may be. Right now, what you have is like me giving a handwaving argument and then saying it's a proof because what's true is a "matter of taste".

Comment: @DerekElkins I added a last bullet point to elaborate on constructivity. It is indeed constructive in the sense I'm used to, but I acknowledge that it is not the only possible view. The original question did not define what constructivity is (a later comment did), so I took the liberty to interpret things in the way I know best.